# Extern stuct in C source files

Tags: c, struct, pthreads, mutex, extern

I am trying to have a dictionary_object structure named dict_obj available in two separate .c files. This is while trying to write a pthread TCP server for a class. I have not worked much with C before and am having a difficult time getting this figured out. I'm not sure if I'm declaring this as an external structure correctly as netbeans is throwing off errors on clean and build saying invalid use of undefined type.

In db_functions.c I have:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                Server Function & Variable Initialization 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct dictionary_object dict_obj;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                            Server Function Codes:
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                         Database Initialization
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int db_initialization()
{

    dict_obj.word_count = 0;
    return 1;
```

In db_operations.c I have:

```
struct dictionary_object
{
    char dictionary[DICTIONARY_SIZE][WORD_LENGTH];
    int word_count;
    pthread_mutex_t dict_mutex;

};

extern struct dictionary_object dict_obj;
```

Hopefully this gives you guys enough idea of what I'm trying to accomplish without having to overwhelm you with too much code. Thanks in advance! Let me know if you need to see more of the code.

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: Um, what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the structure contents and layout once in an include file.  Also define the "extern" definitions for all functions and statics for the code there.   In any file wanting to use those structs or definitions, include the header file (something like db_struct.h).

db_struct.h:

```
struct dictionary_obhect {
   char dictionary ...
}
extern struct dictionary_object dict_obj;
extern int db_initialization();
```

db_struct.c:

```
#include "db_struct.h"

struct dictionary_object dict_obj;
int db_initiatilization() {
    dict_obc.word_count = 0;
}
```

Note this is all pretty old-style C code.  Modern C++ etc. have other means of doing similar things.

Comment: You don't need the `extern` for `int db_initialization();`

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that your problem is that the C compiler complains that it doesn't know how to allocate memory for a `struct dictionary_object` when it compiles db_functions.c. Its confusion is understandable because the file you're asking it to compile doesn't tell it what `struct dictionary_object` is at all.

You should move the definition of the struct to a *header file* that both of your `.c` files include.

Comment: any way to keep this in the existing c files and make it work?

Comment: @user1048382: Why would you even want to do that? If you put the definition in the `.c` files, you would have to make sure the _same_ definition appeared in _each_ `.c` file, and if you need to change it later you would need to change it everywhere, creating a large risk of error if you forget changing one of the copies. The point of having it in a `.h` file is that it allows you to write the definition only once.

Comment: (If you accidentally put _different_ definitions in different .c files, they will appear to compile and link OK, but the machine code that result from the two compilations will be based on different assumptions about the memory layout of the structure, so they will not work correctly together at runtime).

Comment: just ask for knowledge purposes... you know as a FYI but for my information. Didn't mean to upset or offend you.